# Import arcpy using PyScripter or IDLE gives No module named RuntimeError?

Tags: arcpy, installation, pyscripter, idle, importerror

I'm trying to figure out this problem. Yesterday I installed PyScripter and since then, scripts doesn't work. When I run any script (in PyScripter or IDLE) which uses "import arcpy", I get this error message:

```
import arcpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 17, in     <module>
    from geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from _base import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\arcgisscripting.py", line 81, in <module>
    from RuntimeError import RuntimeError
ImportError: No module named RuntimeError
```

Are there any suggestions on a potential to fix?

Comment: I'm confident that an uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS for Desktop with Python will at least get IDLE working again.

Comment: Do you thing that is possible to try to solve the problem without reinstalling ArcGIS?

Comment: It will depend on your skillset and experience, for me, I would find an uninstall/reinstall to be the expedient.

Comment: Reinstall Python and ArcGIS solve the problem.. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confident that an uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS for Desktop with Python will at least get IDLE working again.

Although there may be ways to avoid doing this, employing them successfully will depend on your skillset and experience, and for me, I would find an uninstall/reinstall to be the expedient.

Comment: FYI on my windows machine I've had to play around with the environment variables repeatedly to curtail this problem of not being able to find whatever python library.